# QGIS Mosaicing with null values in images

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, image-mosaic, qgis-2.2

I have a set of landuse landcover data which needs to be mosaiced.

Whenever i try using QGIS Raster>miscellenous>merge tool. giving no datavalue as '0', it returns either

**(A)**

```
 ' Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 509, in 
sys.exit(main()) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 495, in main 
fi.copy_into( t_fh, band, band, nodata ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 241, in copy_into 
nodata_arg ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 61, in raster_copy 
nodata ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 101, in raster_copy_with_nodata 
to_write = Numeric.choose( nodata_test, (data_src, data_dst) ) 
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGISVA~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 296, in choose 
return choose(choices, out=out, mode=mode) 
MemoryError
```

or

**(B)**

' The process crashed sometime after starting successfully'

I am using QGIS 2.2 on Windows 8 PC.

I have a set of 30 images in .tiff format which needs to be mosaiced. I also tried doing it with 2-3 images but the same problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

You are running into a memory error.

According to this mailing list posts from the developers:

http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/fwtools/2006-October/000531.html

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2010-January/023310.html

you should better use gdalwarp for such purposes.

Comment: If one were trying to use conversion -> rasterize and receive that same error, does that entail the same issue - a memory error?

Comment: Start with a raster size of 10x10 cells. if that works, but higher resolution fails, you run into a memory error. You might get further using `gdal_rasterize` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to have a physical mosaic file, but rather the results of the mosaic, you could use a Virtual Raster (Raster - Misc - Build Virtual Raster). With this tool you can generate a mosaic'd image from rasters, and identify no data values.

Comment: i do need a physical mosaic file. is it possible to save the virtual raster into a physical file?

Comment: A virtual raster is a physical file (.vrt), but it is just a linking file. The virtual raster will be very small in size. Also, if you move the .vrt without the source files, the mosaic will be broken

Answer (score 0):

Could it be helpful to go though Raster/Analysis/Fill 'nodata' first, and try to merge after?
It allows you to fill the nodata value for an entire folder in batch, for *.bil extensions and others.

(Given my version is in dutch - I'm just translating straightforward.)